# Why is there a difference between gpu frame extracting and CPU frame extracting using ffmpeg？

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

I used ffmpeg for gpu frame extraction, but it was different from CPU frame extraction.

gpu frame extraction command:

```
ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i video.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf "scale_npp=format=yuv420p,fps=25,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" -pix_fmt yuvj420p -y images/%5d.jpg
```

cpu frame extraction command:

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -i video.mp4 -q:v 2 -vf fps=25 -y images/%5d.jpg
```

But the results are different?
why?